# RestKit Date Parsing Uses Incorrect Timezone

Tags: objective-c, timezone, nsdate, restkit

If part of the data that RestKit gets from my server is a timestamp formatted as `2013-05-27 20:32:26 UTC`, and later I want to find out the difference between the current time and this date, I do

```
NSTimeInterval difference = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateFromRestKit];
```

But this always seems to be off for me by 1 hour, and I'm guessing this is because I'm on BST, which is UTC+1. So I think that RestKit is ignoring the timezone specified in the date string, and is instead parsing the date using the current system timezone.

I understand that there may be some technical reason it ignores the time zone, but I found all this time stuff really difficult to get my ahead around so I'm not sure.

How can I work out the correct difference between the times?

Comment: The timestamp you list doesn't include the time zone. Is the server sending out UTC (which is what RestKit expects).

Comment: @Wain yes, the time coming from the server is in UTC.

Comment: @Wain the timestamp I included says UTC at the end, surely that's the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your timestamp contains the `UTC` format , try to specify the timezone for it again.

If you want the resulting difference of two date timezone in '`UTC`' then , convert the other one in `UTC` format and then find the time Interval.

Do let me know , if any query. Or if possible , post your code , to get more clear about your question. (:

Comment: I'm trying to find the difference, but the time that RestKit gives me is off. How would I specify the timezone?

Comment: As in your question , the restkit time is "2013-05-27 20:32:26 UTC". That means your time zone is with UTC Format.